# Input inside Modal with Php + Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a page that contain the following form:

https://jsfiddle.net/5tzg8kzm/9/

```
<body>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
```

Where the users must fill all the fields.

When the user click at the button " Open modal ", a modal is open, but I want to add 2 input field inside modal, is it possible?

Comment: what you have try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, inside 
     `<div class="modal-body">` you insert code here `<input type="text"> </div>`